# Software for Quantum Computing

Tags: quantum-algorithms, programming, ibm-q-experience, applications, nisq

From what I read classical computing evolved so quickly because of the funding-applications cycle. Even though the cost to make denser IC's was increasing rapidly, the applications were also getting better and wider so people put lot more money. Thus they were able to scale well with Moore's law. We need to build such a cycle for Quantum computing since it won't happen naturally as we can't expect quantum supremacy to be the first step that draws a ton of money.

So I was wondering how could I build applications for NISQ's or any basic few qubit systems practically implemented. For example what is the software that I can help build right now ? What kind of software are people looking for ? What has already been done and what can be done in next year or so ?

Answer (score 1):

You can participate in and contribute to open-source [Qiskit](https://github.com/Qiskit).

You can write tools to work with Qiskit and/or other development kits, e.g., my [qis_job](https://github.com/jwoehr/qis_job) which makes it easy to run a .qasm file right away.

You can write your own toys! See my [quantum_yiqing](https://github.com/jwoehr/quantum_yiqing).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to try writing code for quantum computers using something from the Lisp family of languages instead of Python, which is used by most people in this field, I wrote a GNU Guile (Scheme) to QASM2 toy compiler called [g2q](https://github.com/PESchoenberg/g2q)